# Using a function publicly in base class and privately in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a function `public void myFunction(foo);` and `public void myFunction(foo, bar);` in my parent class. I want these functions included in my derived class, but privately. You can declare it in the derived class' private section by `using BaseClass::myFunction()`. Note that it doesnt take any parameters in the function. But if there are two implementations of `myFunction` like I have in my case, it won't work since it can't distinguish between the two functions. How do I implement both functions privately?

Comment: what are you trying to prevent?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I will say that this approach (if you can get it to work) is likely to be very confusing, and is not the intended way to use inheritance. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Inheritance bestows a `is-a` relationship. A object that is of the class `Trout` that is derived from `Fish` happens to be a `Fish`. Everything that is legal to do on a "pure" `Fish` is legal to do on a `Trout`, as it *is* a `Fish`. That is a core idea of OOP. If that is not desired, you most likely do not have a case in which you should use inheritance. Is there a reason you can't use aggregation instead? Other than that, how about private inheritance?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it’s not my way of making it. Professors orders. We’re making a LinkedList class from scratch and an OrderedLinkedList as a derived class. He says our push_back function must be publicly accessible for the LL class but cannot be publicly accessed in the OLL class

Comment: You can do a `private` inheritance instead of `public` one, like this: `class Derived: private Base {};`. It will change visibility of everything from base class to be `private` in context of derived class. But I don't think I ever saw a valid use case for non-public inheritance.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit just added a comment, check below!

Comment: What you want to do is a *kind of* a use-case for private inheritance, but it violates Liskov Substitution Principle (letter L in SOLID rules). I think it would be better to extract common base class for both `LinkedList` and `OrderedLinkedList`, so that such shenanigans are not needed, but if your assignment requires `OrderedLinkedList` to derive from `LinkedList`, then you have to ignore good programming style.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thank you, that explains all of the downvoted

Comment: Y'know, just _once_ I'd like to hear of an educational institution that taught _good_ programming.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess students from good educational institutions wouldn't have to come here?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Heh, perhaps. Although, I'd like to think my educational institution was alright and I'm here :D

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've said in your comment about your professor's instruction to use inheritance, more than whether it's a good design choice, I think you are expected to use private inheritance.

Private inheritance is a valid feature of C++, but its often not a good design choice. I wont go into that, I'm not recommending it in general, I'll leave you to look it up elsewhere on SO, but also recommend Scott Meyer's books effective C++ & more effective C++ which covers this.

(protected inheritance on the other hand is very unusual)

In your question you seem to be starting from public inheritance and trying to make some inherited functionality private via using. This is a bad design choice as mentioned in comments. It violates the Liskov substitution principle. Since PUBLIC inheritance implies is-a, we can imagine the code that creates a base class reference to an object of the derived type, what then is supposed to happen when we try to call the hidden functionality with that base class reference?

```
Derived d;
Base& b = d;
b.HiddenFunction(); // calling the function on d even though you thought you hid it
```

If instead you use private inheritance you can then use using to publicise those privately inherited functions which are safe to expose on the derived class.

```
class OrderedLinkedList : private LinkedList
{
     public:
     using LinkedList::ItemCount;  // expose some specific base functionality
};
```

If using doesn't do the job due to overloaded functions, then you can add just those overloads that you want to provide and implement them just by calling the base function. In such cases, if you need to clarify whether to call the base or derived version you can prefix the function name with the class name e.g.

```
void SomeFunction()
{
    // call base version, not this derived version recursively
    NameOfBaseClass::SomeFunction();
}
```

Within the derived class implementation, the public and protected members of the (privately) inherited base class are accessible without the need to do anything like add a using.

Private inheritance is not an is-a relationship like public inheritance since we cannot refer to the derived objects as references/pointers to the base. Private inheritance is "implemented-in-terms-of".

Since private inheritance is not an is-a, one cannot substitute such derived objects for the base and as such the liskov substitution principle just doesn't apply.